# Russian language Mulamadhyamakakarika?

Tags: mahayana, nagarjuna

Would anyone have any advice on where to find a good Russian translation of Nagarjuna's book? (I've tried myself, but Russian is no longer my first language!)

Comment: I'm not sure whether if there's a Russian translation of the book. You can find the english version on Amazon tho.

Comment: Thanks, I have a few copies myself (Garfield, my aim is to supplant the Gideon bible tradition by dumping these and the Tao Te Ching onto unexpecting hotel clients!) - wanted to show it to my dad, who doesn't speak English.

Comment: That's going to be hard. Hopefully someone has the Russian translation. Good luck :D

Comment: Unfortunately I can't assist on this one. Just wondering if you had any luck so far? Do you know of any russian translators that might be able to translate it for you?

Comment: Nope, I'm just gonna give it a go myself - good for the language practice I think!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Androsov has translated and commented it. I'm not sure if his translation is very good - he might have some strange terminology sometimes - but he is one of the leading Russian scholars in that field. See "*Nagarjuna's teaching on Middle Way*" - Андросов В.П. Учение Нагарджуны о Срединности... М., 2006

[image: Androsov, page 2]

Another interesting text on the topic might be *Chandrakirti's "Introduction to Madhyamaka"*:

Чандракирти. Введение в Мадхьямику. Перевод с тибетского, предисловие, комментарии, глоссарий, и указатели Донца А. М. под общей редакцией Монтлевича В, М, – СПб.: Евразия, 2004. – 464 с. ISBN 5-8071-0165-0

ББК 86.39 УДК 2 418 Научное издание Утверждено к печати ученым советом Института монголоведения, буддологии и тибетологии СО РАН Ответственный редактор канд. филос. наук С. П. Нестеркин Рецензенты доктор филос. наук С. Ю. Лепехов доктор филос. наук, профессор В. Б. Цыбикжапов